# Using a conditional statement so jquery fadeIn/fadeOut only works when viewport >= 480px

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code which fades between an image and a heading:

```
setInterval(function(){
            $('.fadein-effect > img').fadeOut(2500, function(){
                $('.fadein-effect').append('<h2 class="intro-text">Site Currently Under Construction - Coming Soon!</h2>');
                $('.fadein-effect > h2').hide().fadeIn(2500).fadeOut(2500, function(){
                    $('.fadein-effect > h2').remove();
                    $('.fadein-effect > img').fadeIn(2500);
                });
            });  
        }, 10000);
```

I want to use this effect in a responsive layout and only want the fade effect to work when the viewport is => 480px. I've tried using the following approach (among many others) but can't get it to work.

```
function fadeInEffect(){
    var $containerWidth = $(window).width();
    if ($containerWidth <= 480) {

        setInterval(function(){
            $('.fadein-effect > img').fadeOut(2500, function(){
                $('.fadein-effect').append('<h2 class="intro-text">Site Currently Under Construction - Coming Soon!</h2>');
                $('.fadein-effect > h2').hide().fadeIn(2500).fadeOut(2500, function(){
                    $('.fadein-effect > h2').remove();
                    $('.fadein-effect > img').fadeIn(2500);
                });
            });
        }, 10000);

    }
    else {
        $('.fadein-effect > img').replaceWith('<h2 class="intro-text">Site Currently Under Construction - Coming Soon!</h2>');
    } 
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    fadeInEffect();//run when page first loads
});

$(window).resize(function () {
    fadeInEffect();//run on every window resize
});
```

I'm fairly new to jquery/javascript so could be doing something wrong that's pretty basic. I've been struggling with this for a while so any help would be most appreciated,

Thanks,

Thomas

Comment: You have your comparative operator backwards. Use `>=` (greater than or equal to) instead of `<=` (less than or equal to).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your original code works just fine, you just have the wrong operator in your `if` statement. Instead of using "less than or equal to" (`<=`), you should use "greater than or equal to" (`>=`).

```
if ($containerWidth >= 480) {
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/d5op9bty/

I hope this helps. ^^

Comment: If that resolved the issue, please mark my answer as the solution so others can see where the problem was and potentially identify it in their code. ^^

Answer (score 0):

You could use matchMedia API wich is supported from IE >= 9

```
if (window.matchMedia("(max-width: 480px)").matches) {
  // code executed once here
}
```

http://caniuse.com/#feat=matchmedia